# perform live, frame-by-frame analysis from camera2 preview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, analysis, android-camera2

I am working on android app in which I need to conduct real-time, frame-by-frame analysis on the preview in the CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession while recording a video. The framework ensures a consistent preview frame rate of 30 FPS during the video recording session at 120 FPS.

I have also tried CameraX api but it is not configurable to have 120FPS. Therefore, I am using ConstrainedHighSpeed API.

I have used ImageReader to capture the preview frames but it is giving error that this surface is not supported.

```
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
            mVideoSize!!.width, mVideoSize!!.height,
            ImageFormat.YUV_420_888,  /*maxImages*/2
        )
        mImageReader!!.setOnImageAvailableListener(
            mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler
        )
```

To achieve this, I am utilizing the AutoFitSurfaceView for the preview. The code for this class is from google camera-samples.

However, I am currently encountering difficulties in capturing the frames from the preview for analysis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [constrained high speed capture session](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession) is unfortunately labeled 'constrained' for a good reason; it's very [inflexible](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_CONSTRAINED_HIGH_SPEED_VIDEO):

> The application creates a camera capture session with no more than 2 surfaces via CameraDevice.createConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession(List, StateCallback, Handler). The targeted surfaces must be preview surface (either from SurfaceView or SurfaceTexture) or recording surface(either from MediaRecorder.getSurface() or MediaCodec.createInputSurface()).

So you might be able to run analysis on the GPU via a SurfaceTexture (or do a readback from the GPU, though of course that's even more overhead). But ImageReader won't likely work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that its inflexible, you have mentioned to run analysis on the GPU via a SurfaceTexture. Can you guide me on this one? I really need to implement this things because my project is stuck at this point. Thanks